# R: return a value from one column in a data frame corresponding to the minimum value in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

So I realize the title isn't the best, but I wasn't sure how else to word it. My problem seems like it should be very simple, but I'm very much an R novice so I 'm not sure how to do it.

Let's say I have a data frame such as:

```
X Y
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
```

How would I go about returning the corresponding X value for the minimum Y? In this case, I'd want it to return A since the minimum value in the column Y is 1.

I'm not even sure where to start with this, so forgive my lack of example code, because I don't have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `which.min`

```
with(df, X[which.min(Y)])
#[1] "A"
```

Or suppose you have `duplicate` minimum values in `Y`, you can use `==`. For example

```
 df$Y[3] <- 1
 with(df,X[ Y == min(Y)])
 #[1] "A" "C"
```

`which.min` returns only the index of `first` minimum value

```
 with(df, X[which.min(Y)])
 #[1] "A"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Y = 1:5), .Names =
c("X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, Y == min(Y))
```

For X value only:

```
filter(df, Y == min(Y)) %>% select(X)
```

Or:

```
filter(df, Y == min(Y)) %>% .$X
```